# Finding the mode of a list without built-in functions

Tags: python, list, mode

For my programming course, I need to find the mode of a list given by the user. We went through this starting code in class. Now we need to find the single or multiple modes given by the user. Also, when putting in this code, I get an error saying the index is out of range. Please help and thank you in advance!

```
def calculateMode(dataList):
    dataList.sort()
    position = 0
    largestCount = 0
    listLength = len(dataList)
    while(position <= listLength):
        count = dataList.count(dataList[position])
        if(count > largestCount):
            largestCount = count
            valuePosition = dataList[position]
        position += count
    return dataList[valuePosition]

userList = []
listEntry = float(input("Enter a number (Enter -1 to end):  "))
while(listEntry >= 0):
    userList.append(listEntry)
    listEntry = float(input("Enter a number (Enter -1 to end):  "))
print(calculateMode(userList))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterative approach:

1. First get unique elements from the input. In the case of Python you can use **set**
2. Make a new_empty dictionary
3. This dictionary stores **keys as unique elements** and **values as how many times the current element** is repeated in **original input**
4. create a new variable (let us assume for now I created my variable named **max** and initialize it to **zero**) This is mainly done thinking that maximum_occurence of the element is zero
5. Now we will create a loop that gets value from the dictionary. If the value is > than the max value we initiated we will update the value of max with that particular value. we will iterate along with the whole dictionary
6. Here we will get the maximum occurrence value. Next step we will create an empty list that stores the mode values. Again we will iterate along with the dictionary. We will get the values. If that value which we get using a key is equal to that maximum occurrence what we do, is we will store that key I the empty list
7. Then print the mode list
   `Hurray`!!! You got the mode

```py
def find_mode(num_list):
   enter code here # Complete this function
    unique_num_list = list(set(num_list))
    dictionary = {}
    for i in unique_num_list:
        get_count = num_list.count(i)
        dictionary[i]= get_count
    max_repeat = 0 
    for i in unique_num_list:
        get_value = dictionary[i]
        if get_value>max_repeat:
            max_repeat = get_value
    result = ''
    for i in unique_num_list:
        if dictionary[i]==max_repeat:
            result = result+str(i)+" "
    return result


num_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
# Call the appropriate functions and print the results
mode = find_mode(num_list)
print(mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

the list index begin at 0, so the ending index should be length of list - 1

```
while(position < listLength):
```

the best way to find mode is using dict. the key is user input. value is the frequency.

```
def mode(data):
    return sorted(data.items(),key = lambda x: x[1],reverse = True )[0][0]

print mode(  {1:10,10:1,100:4,4:10,5:30,7:3 }) 

5
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Python's "count" method or by utilizing hash tables.
Since this is homework I can't give you the answer directly but I will say that you can create a **dictionary** of the unique elements of the list and how many items are in that list.

With a dict, you won't even need to sort the list to count it.

Once you have that, you can find the **keys** of the **maximum values** of the dict.

I've been told it's bad practice to use ints as dictionary keys but I think in this case you'll be okay :)

This can also be done w/ tuples but I find hash tables to be the most effective thing for problems like these.

```
while(position <= listLength):     #Definitely a better idea to use *for* here
        count = dataList.count(dataList[position])
        if(count > largestCount):
            largestCount = count
            valuePosition = dataList[position]
        position += count
    return dataList[valuePosition]
```

Your code here breaks because when position == listLength it will iterate through the list an nth time. n > listLength in this case. Remember, your 0 indexing and Python 0 indexes. Try listLength-1 if you'd like to keep this practice.